# Terraform's OpenStack provider: Error: One of 'auth_url` or 'cloud` must be specified

Tags: terraform, openstack

When I run `terraform apply` (but not `terraform validate`) I get the following error,

> Error: Invalid provider configuration
>
> Provider "registry.terraform.io/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack" requires explicit configuration. Add a provider block to the root module and configure the provider's required arguments as described in the provider documentation.

Immediately followed by,

> Error: One of `auth_url` or `cloud` must be specified
>
> ```
>  with provider["registry.terraform.io/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack"],
>  on <empty> line 0:
>    (source code not available)
> ```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had to generate this was my provider had an alias,

```
provider "openstack" {
  alias       = "acmecorp"
  tenant_name = "admin"
  cloud       = "openstack"
}
```

That `alias` caused this problem, and removing it resolved the error. But looking at the specific [`terraform-provider-openstack/openstack` provider documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs) `alias` isn't mentioned. I pulled the alias convention from AWS and it seems to not be supported with OpenStack.

[I opened #1480 for a better error message](https://github.com/terraform-provider-openstack/terraform-provider-openstack/issues/1480)